# FullCalendar v4 change color of selected date

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to change the background-color of a clicked date and it's working but now I need to manage that the only one with new background-color is the last I clicked.

Is there a way to control this?

Date click event

```
calendardateClick = (info) => {
    info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = '#CAFFDC';
}
```

Calendar mapper

```
let calendar_mapper = {
        plugins : ['dayGrid','timeGrid','list','interaction'],
        header : {
            left : 'prev,next today',
            center : 'title',
            right : 'timeGridWeek, dayGridMonth, timeGridDay'
        },
        editable : false,
        allDaySlot : false,
        events : this.eventLIST,
        dateClick : this.calendardateClick
    }
```

Comment: Could you make the days ["selectable"](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting)? You could also customize the selection background color.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the style directly, give each clicked date a class (whose rule is to set the background colour). Then, when another one is clicked, you can simply use `document.querySelectorAll` to find all elements with that class, and remove that class from all of them, before adding it to the new one.

CSS:

```
.selectedDate
{
  background-color: #CAFFDC !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
  var days = document.querySelectorAll(".selectedDate");
  days.forEach(function(day) {
    day.classList.remove("selectedDate");
  });
  info.dayEl.classList.add("selectedDate");
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWYpKeE